# Why can't I do a for loop containing \?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

When it comes to most trouble-making characters, like `&`, you can smuggle them around by wrapping the string in quotation marks. However, for certain characters in certain contexts, it doesn't work:

```
@echo off
for %%u in ("hello\?there" "general kenobi") do (
    echo %%u
)
```

This just returns `"general kenobi"`. Same if you replace `\?` with `\*` or `"` or `\"`. Why is this, and is there a workaround? I want to be able to do a for loop with a list of URL's that may or may not contain `\?`.

Comment: It's `*` or `?` causing the "issue", since these characters constitute [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html), which instruct `for` to search the file system for matching files; the `\ `is the Windows path separator, so `hello\?there` lets `for` search for files in the sub-directory `hello` of the current directory a file whose name is a single character followed by `there`...

Comment: Huh, I thought I already tried it with just `?` but I guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with arrays. Won't work if the URL contains `"`, though. As for why the problem occurs, see aschipfl's comment.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET index_list=
SET n=1

:loop
SET url=
SET /P url="Enter url: "
SET url="%url%"
IF %url%=="" GOTO endloop
SET url[%n%]=%url%
SET index_list=%index_list% %n%
SET /A n+=1
GOTO loop
:endloop

SET index_list=%index_list:~1%

FOR %%n IN (%index_list%) DO (
    ECHO !url[%%n]!
)
```

Comment: You really should learn how to use `set` with safe and recommended syntax, i.e. `Set "VariableName=StringValue"`.